# Overriding spring config server configuration from command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have a spring config server running on localhost on port 8888. Here's a snippet from the relevant properties file:

```
server.port=8085
ideal.connection.threshold.millis=600000
listener.port=3042
number.of.backlog.ports=1000
```

I am trying to override these properties from command line. I have tried -- and the -D variations, both before and after the <application_name>.jar, but to no avail. The application still picks up the properties from the spring config server.

Things I've tried

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=<profile_name> -Dlistener.port=3034 -Dserver.port=9096-Xmx2048m -jar listener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
java -Dspring.profiles.active=<profile_name> --listener.port=3034 --server.port=9096-Xmx2048m -jar listener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
java -Dspring.profiles.active=<profile_name> -Xmx2048m -jar listener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --listener.port=3034 --server.port=9096
java -Dspring.profiles.active=<profile_name> -Xmx2048m -jar listener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dlistener.port=3034 -Dserver.port=9096
```

None of the above approaches work, in fact the second approach results in

```
Unrecognized option: --listener.port=3034
```

as it should. The other 3 options result in the config being picked up from the spring-config server.

So my question is, is there a way to override the spring config server at all, and if so, what is the right way to override the configurations in the spring config server?

Comment: I never claimed  it was. 

These are application-specific properties in the spring config server. I am trying to override a couple of them, and they aren't working. So I am looking for a way to override _any_ property, else an authentic answer which says it isn't possible. If it makes you happier, I would  to override, say, ideal.connection.threshold.millis or number.of.backlog.ports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Spring Cloud Config server, the remote configurations override system configurations (i.e.: command-line arguments are replaced by the remote configs coming from the config server).

To replace this behavior, add the `spring.cloud.config.override-system-properties` to `false` in your `application.properties`.

Comment: Can I pass this flag via command line? `--spring.cloud.config.override-system-properties=false`

Comment: @AntonDuzenko. . .I've never tested it out, but I don't see why you could not. . .

Answer (score 1):

There is a correct and accepted answer to this question, I just thought I'd add some more details.

The official Spring Cloud Config documentation [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html) is quite confusing and misleading. In particular,

> The property sources that are added to you application by the
> bootstrap context are often "remote" (e.g. from a Config Server), and
> by default they cannot be overridden locally, except on the command
> line.

It is clear that properties in the config server cannot be overridden via command line, *unless* you explicitly set the property

`spring.cloud.config.override-system-properties` to either `true` or `false` in the relevant properties file. If you set it to `false`, then only the command line, environment variables, and system properties can override the properties. It it is set to `true`, then your applications's local config file can override the properties as well.

Thus, if your application name is `foo` and active profile is `bar`, then your `foo-bar.properties` should have the `spring.cloud.config.override-system-properties` set to `true` or `false`.

Note that properties such as application name, profile and the cloud config (things that you'd put in your bootstrap.* file) can, of course, be overridden from the command line.

A big thank you to [this github issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/907), which documents this problem.

Comment: The github issue mentioned that the comments were fixed, not sure as to why the documentation at https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html has still not been fixed.

Comment: I have not had the occassion to use multiple active profiles, will update the answer when and if I do so.